# Tomcat Web Application threads stuck in Service Stage - causing app hang-ups

Tags: multithreading, tomcat, isapi

We are using Tomcat 6 / IIS to host our Java MVC web applications (Spring MVC and Frontman). We started running into problems recently when we see threads stuck in the Service stage for hours.
Using Lambda Probe we see the threads start to pile up and eventually the app becomes unresponsive. The processing time increases, zero bytes in or out. The url is reachable and the logs show that it starts but never finishes.

`IP Stage processing time bytes-in bytes-out url

111.11.111.111 Service  00:57:26.0  0b  0b  GET /Application/command/monitor` 

All of this is on a test server set up as follows:
ISAPI filter worker:

`worker.testuser.type=ajp13

worker.testuser.host=localhost

worker.testuser.port=8009

worker.testuser.socket_timeout=300

worker.testuser.connection_pool_timeout=600`


Server.xml:

`<
Connector

  port="8009" 
  protocol="AJP/1.3"

        redirectPort="8443"

        tomcatAuthentication="false"

        connectionTimeout="6000"

        />`

Any thoughts on why this happens or how to configure Tomcat to kill ancient application threads?

Comment: Thread dump would be more than useful. Can be anonymised.

Answer (score 0):

Can use java monitoring package to get the all the thread and thread dumps and kill using the thread id (though thread stop is deprecated it does the work)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/overview.html